# Django - booleanfield checked init

Tags: django, django-forms

I want initialize my booleanfield in my form ?

Example : booleanfield is checked when I open the page.

How make ?

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter`initial` during field initialization (read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial)):

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    your_field = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)
```

OR
You can do it in `__init__` method:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    your_field = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['your_field'].initial = True
```

You can also do it on form creation step:

```
form = MyForm(initial={'your_field': True})
```

Comment: But how init this in __init__ ?

Comment: @YassVegas I have updated an answer with two other methods.

Comment: I'm confused.. it don't works :o. In my templte I call the field with this method : {{ nameOfMyForm.my_field }}

Comment: @YassVegas It should. Then show your template, view and form please.